# Compiler features conflicting while importing macros

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I'm trying to use some of the macros from the diesel crate but they say they have not been imported, even when explicitly imported.

I Think the problem is coming from the use the feature decl_macro. This feature is required by rocket in order to use some of the unsafe macros "[rustc E0658] [E] `macro` is experimental" but I am not sure.

The way the rocket-rs documentation says to use diesel is by using `rocket_contrib::databases::diesel`.
The thing I want to use is at `rocket_contrib::databases::diesel::prelude::Insertable` or just `diesel::prelude::Insertable`, and table_name in the same location.

Here is the code I have for the imports

```rs
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
use rocket::request::{Form, FromForm};
use rocket::Request;
use rocket::*;

#[macro_use] extern crate rocket_contrib;

use rocket_contrib::databases::diesel;
use rocket_contrib::databases::diesel::prelude::*;

// --snip--
```

Here is the code that says Insertable and the macro table_name are missing

```rs
// --snip--
#[derive(Insertable, Debug)]
#[table_name="redirects"]
pub struct Redirect<'a> {
    pub alias: &'a String,
    pub url: &'a String,
    pub count: &'a i64,
}
```

The errors I get are these

```
error: cannot find derive macro `Insertable` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 | #[derive(Insertable, Debug)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
error: cannot find attribute `table_name` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:3
   |
21 | #[table_name="redirects"]
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I have tried:

- removing the decl_macro
- adding proc_macro_hygiene as a feature
- using the diesel::prelude::* instead of rocket_contrib::databases::diesel::prelude::*
- using #[macro_use] extern crate diesel

The goal is to use the rocket_contrib, while keeping decl_macro enabled for rocket, and still having things like table_name and Insertable imported from diesel.

Comment: `diesel::prelude::Insertable` is the trait, not the derive macro that implements it.  Use `diesel::Insertable` instead.